# Get index by value regarding combobox for win apps c#

Tags: c#, winforms

we can easily get index of combobox using **FindString** method

```
int index = cboCountryTwoCode.FindString(localJob.DeliveryCountryTwoCode.Trim());
cboCountryTwoCode.SelectedIndex = index;
```

so i just need to know is there any way to get index of combobox just finding by value instead of finding by text. please let me know is there any similar. if anything not there then how to achieve my objective that get index of combobox just finding by value. thanks

### this way i am populating my combo

```
        cboCountryTwoCode.DataSource = Utility.LoadCountry();
        cboCountryTwoCode.DisplayMember = "CData";
        cboCountryTwoCode.ValueMember = "CValue";
```

**LoadCountry()** will return datatable . thanks

Comment: What environment? Winforms? ASP.NET? Silverlight? More info needed.

Comment: I suppose, its winforms as written in the title.

Comment: i am talking about winform...i know how to handle this situation in asp.net webform project. if anyone has any idea then plzz share with me...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinForms, `ComboBox` doesn't have an explicit key/value list of items.  It has an `ObjectCollection` for `Items`.

I think you could implement `ToString()` on your objects to display its proper descriptions.

Then you should use some LINQ to find the correct item. Something like this:

```
class MyType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}

var selectedObject = cb.Items.Cast<MyType>().SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(myId));
```

Comment: if i populate or bind my combo with datatable then how could i cast like cb.Items.Cast<MyType>() this line. can i write like cb.Items.Cast<Datatable>() ? is it correct.

Comment: Try `cb.Items.Cast<DataRow>().SingleOrDefault(r => r["CValue"].Equals(myValue))`